# use of "lest" grammar

Tags: grammar

I'll go straight to the point, I was reading an article in the NYT

> he never put his uniform back on, LEST he become the target of protesters.

May you help to understand how to use it ? Is it of common usage?

Answer (score 0):

[lest](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/lest) - for fear that; "she tiptoed lest her mother should hear her"

This is a somewhat archaic term that still appears in modern speech and writing from time to time. It is very common in the Authorized Version of the Bible. Also note that it is pronounced with a short "e" sound, like "best." Many people mispronounce it as "least."

Comment: Thank you RobJarvis, would you suggest to use it in common language or not?

Comment: You should not use it often but it can be useful to express a warning or something unwanted. It sounds a little old-fashioned and formal. Note that the following verb is usually in the subjunctive.

Comment: I use it rarely, and then mainly for effect, to call attention to the consequences of a particular action.